# What is the frame rate of the Hobbit Blu-ray release?

Tags: the-hobbit, distribution

I don't know if Blu-ray supports 48fps - is only 24fps version available?

Comment: I'd say this was a *technical* question not a recommendation question. Which should be on topic.

Comment: Blu ray supports different combinations of resolution and fps, close to 48 fps among them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-ray#Video I don't know about The Hobbit specifically.

Answer (score 4):

24 frames.

> "High-definition (1080-line) television is also interlaced—hence the 1080i designation. But 1080p high-definition movies are progressively drawn line after line—they're not interlaced. In fact, Blu-ray actually displays at 30 fps regardless of the source material. Using a method called 2:3 pulldown, it distributes the frames to display 24 fps film footage properly at 30 fps." -PC Mag ([The Hobbit' at 48fps: Frame Rates Explained](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2403746,00.asp))

Comment: Is Blu-ray capable of displaying more than 30 frames per second?

Comment: From what little I've read the simple  answer is no. http://forum.blu-ray.com/showthread.php?t=210147      Note: I changed my answer from 30fps to 24fps. I did this because from what I've read 24fps not 30fps is standard. I know the article says it distributes film at 30fps, but the indicated frame rate from a film on Bluray is 24fps so that is what I'm going to go with.